# Remote deployment on WAS using websphere deployer plugin of jenkins

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to deploy an application on websphere application server(8.5.5) from Jenkins using websphere deployer plugin. I have attached the two required jars. I can telnet the WAS server from jenkins server. I am receiving a connection successful message for Test connection button present in webspere deployer plugin.

I am receiving following error:

```
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.DeploymentServiceException: Failed to install artifact: Failure uploading archive to server
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.installArtifact(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:167)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.deployArtifact(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:193)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:171)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1046)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
```

I am not sure why this is coming. I tried to manually deploy application and that went well. After that when I tried to redeploy it using this plugin, it uninstalls the manually deployed application but fails while uploading new one.

Any guess why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. From past days I have been checking the console output of jenkins but not "jenkins.err.log" file. There I have found UnknownHostException which is solved by adding the remote ip address into my hosts file.